# What kind of propellers are generally mounted on the Aeriane Sirocco?

Tags: propeller

I'm curious what propeller is used for the Aeriana Sirocco. Online I see lots of pictures of propellers with [three blades](http://speleotrove.com/sirocco/files/sirocco_ul_niederlande_weiss_.jpg), but none with only two and I cannot find many clear pictures of the proppeler. Are there any Aeriana Sirocco aircraft flying around with (wooden) propellers with only two blades?

Comment: It's powered by a Rotax 447, and there are a ton of props you can use for that, mostly composites (carbon) and some wood, with or without reinforcement.

Comment: @JuanJimenez thank you a lot!

Comment: If this is the same aircraft as the Aviasud Sirocco then you can see lots of pictures in Google image search and many have a two-bladed prop.